# Angularjs error: Font from origin 'http://getbootstrap.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on an Angularjs web app and I'm almost done with my UI but I'm getting this error that says,

"Font from origin 'http://getbootstrap.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

I've compared my code to my other working code and I can't seem to find the problem. I've also searched around to see if anyone's having the same problem but everyone else is having JQUERY or some type of JSON problem. This is a bootstrap error which is really confusing me because I can't find exactly where in my code is giving me this error. Any ideas? Thanks

edit:

Here's a snippet of my dependencies:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="user.js"></script>
<!--<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client_UI.css">
```

Comment: Can you show us a snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: `getbootstrap.com` is not a CDN! Don't hotlink to it! Use http://www.bootstrapcdn.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can't find the line in my code that's hotlink to getbootstrap.com. Will post my dependancies. Thanks

Comment: Have you solved this? I am currently having the same problem. bootstrap is loading "../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.xxx" and it's a Cross-Origin Resource. I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: @LemLordjeKo I did. I had a reference to getbootstrap.com on my css file. Lemme know if this helps